# Python list comprehension Django objects

Tags: python, django, list, list-comprehension

I am developing a dictionary Django app where `Definition`s have `Tag`s. I have written this generic function to collect all `Tag`s from a list of `Definition`s.

This is my current working version:

```
def get_tags(definitions):
    tags = []
    for d in definitions:
        tags += d.tags.all()
    return tags
```

I was trying to accomplish the same using Python's list comprehension:

```
tags = []
return [tags.extend(d.tags.all()) for d in definitions]
```

This code however does not work yet. What am I missing?

Is there an even slicker way to do this in just one line without creating the tags variable, perhaps using yield statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to iterate over all the elements `d.tags.all()`, and thus need a nested list comp:

```
tags = [t for d in definitions for t in d.tags.all()]
```

this is just the list comprehension version of:

```
tags = []
for d in definitions:
    for t in d.tags.all():
        tags.append(t)
```